# How to efficiently join a list with commas and add "and" before the last element

Tags: python, list

I've been going through [Automatetheboringstuff](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/) and came across a challenge called Comma Code (end of [chapter 4](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter4/)). You have to write a function that takes a list and print out a string, joining the elements with a comma and adding "and" before the last element.

Keeping in mind that I am fairly new to python, or programing for that matter, it was still a manageable task, but the output had a comma before the inserted "and". So I revised the code to clean that up. This is my code:

```
def comma_separator(someList):
    """The function comma_separator takes a list and joins it
       into a string with (", ") and adds " and " before the last value."""

    if type(someList) is list and bool(someList) is True:
        return ", ".join(someList[:-1]) + " and " + someList[-1]
    else:
        print("Pass a non-empty list as the argument.")
```

Is there a better way to do it? Is there a module that can do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll have to account for the case where you have just the *one* element:

```
def comma_separator(sequence):
    if not sequence:
        return ''
    if len(sequence) == 1:
        return sequence[0]
    return '{} and {}'.format(', '.join(sequence[:-1]), sequence[-1])
```

Note that `bool(sequence) is True` is a very elaborate way of testing for a non-empty list; simply using `if sequence:` is enough as the `if` statement looks for boolean truth *already*.

Arguably, calling the function with anything other than a sequence (something that can be indexed and has a length) should just result in an exception. You generally do not test for types in functions like these. If you *did* have to test for a type, use `isinstance(sequence, list)` to at least allow for subclasses.

I'd also make it an error to pass in an empty list. You could turn that exception into a `ValueError`:

```
def comma_separator(sequence):
    if len(sequence) > 1:
        return '{} and {}'.format(', '.join(sequence[:-1]), sequence[-1])
    try:
        return sequence[0]
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError('Must pass in at least one element')
```

Demo of the latter:

```
>>> def comma_separator(sequence):
...     if len(sequence) > 1:
...         return '{} and {}'.format(', '.join(sequence[:-1]), sequence[-1])
...     try:
...         return sequence[0]
...     except IndexError:
...         raise ValueError('Must pass in at least one element')
... 
>>> comma_separator(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
'foo, bar and baz'
>>> comma_separator(['foo', 'bar'])
'foo and bar'
>>> comma_separator(['foo'])
'foo'
>>> comma_separator([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in comma_separator
ValueError: Must pass in at least one element
```

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to [Martijn's readable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32008908/21945), you can use two `str.join()`; an inner join that joins with commas all but the last item in the given sequence, and an outer join that joins with `and` the result of the inner join with the last item. It's a one-liner:

```
def comma_separator(seq):
    return ' and '.join([', '.join(seq[:-1]), seq[-1]] if len(seq) > 2 else seq)

>>> comma_separator([])
''
>>> comma_separator(['a'])
'a'
>>> comma_separator(['a', 'b'])
'a and b'
>>> comma_separator(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'a, b and c'
>>> comma_separator(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
'a, b, c and d'
```

This does not treat an empty sequence as an error but instead returns an empty string.

Answer (score -2):

```
', '.join(elements[:-1]) + ' and ' + elements[-1]
```

Comment: This works for a list of size 2 or more. It errors on an empty list, and outputs ' and <item>' on a list size of 1. Still, not bad for a simple one-liner.