# How do I join a list with commas and an 'and'?

Tags: perl

Given a list `(a, b, c)` what is the nicest way to create a string where commas separate all the elements, except the last which is separated by an 'and': `a, b and c`. Ideally this should also work for one and two element lists.

Comment: What are you using? C, C++, C#...

Comment: Question's tagged `perl`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to search for questions before asking one as a similar question has been asked before (but for Python): [How to efficiently join a list with commas and add "and" before the last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008737/how-to-efficiently-join-a-list-with-commas-and-add-and-before-the-last-element)

One way you could do this in perl would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.10;

my @list = qw( a b c );

say join ' and ', $#list ? ( join(', ', @list[0..$#list-1]), $list[-1] ) : @list if @list;
```

Which will print:

- `a` for list `qw( a )`;
- `a and b` for the list `qw( a b )`; and
- `a, b and c` for the list `qw( a b c )`.

If the list is empty, nothing will be printed.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, jamming everything in one statement makes the solution harder to read.

```
sub nice_join {
    my $last = pop;
    return $last if !@_;
    return join(', ', @_) . " and $last";
}
```

If you want something other than undef for no arguments,

```
sub nice_join {
    return "none" if !@_;
    my $last = pop;
    return $last if !@_;
    return join(', ', @_) . " and $last";
}
```

Comment: Oxford comma is more tricky: it doesn't appear in a two member list, and should be followed by a single space :-)

Comment: Perhaps change the second function to `return join(@_==1?' ':', ', @_, "and $last");` ?

Comment: I just dropped that part of my answer. The point of my answer was to show a more readable solution, so I'm going to avoid posting something that turned out to be a little complicated that wasn't requested in the first place.

Comment: Are you serious? That's clearer than what my `join(', ', @list) =~ s/ .* \K , / and/xr` says? 5/6 lines of code? I think maybe you don't know Perl lol. It's a happy day today and the sun is shining and I'm smiling and I have to deal with all you miseries here :D

Comment: First of all, yours was posted 20 minutes after mine. It's not bad (though it's only 2 statements shorter, not 5). It's not perfect, though. It requires Perl 5.14 which is not as common as it should be. (I try to avoid it except as an alternative.) Also, handling of empty lists is suboptimal.

Answer (score 3):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use Test::More;

sub nice_join {
    my @connectors = (q(), (', ') x (@_ - 2), ' and ');
    return join q(), map shift(@connectors) . $_, @_
}

is nice_join(qw( a     )), 'a',          'single';
is nice_join(qw( a b   )), 'a and b',    'double';
is nice_join(qw( a b c )), 'a, b and c', 'treble';

done_testing();
```

For Oxford comma, you need to change the array to

```
my @connectors = (q(), (', ') x (@_ - 2), (',' x (@_ > 2)) . ' and ');
```

Comment: @Bearhug: What do you mean? We don't write tests at work :-)

Answer (score 2):

My thinking is that the easiest way to do what you need is to use join to make a comma separated list, and then turn the final comma into `and`

I think this shows

```
my @list = qw(a b c);

my $nice = join(', ', @list) =~ s/ .* \K , / and/xr;

say $nice;
```

**giving**

```
a, b and c
```

Comment: this will have issues if the values contain a comma.

Comment: @neuhaus: Umm, what is the right result if there are already commas? We don't know do we? So isn't it about an extra checking first? I'm not sure why you say this

Comment: The other solutions don't have problems with entries with a comma in them, they treat them opaquely. That's why I pointed it out.